# Sprocket Error - Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 5.2.0 and I got this error: `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled - Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production` when I open my page home.

I have already set `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css, home.coffe )` but this error still comes.

Here is my `application.html.rb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'%>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    params[:controller] %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller]%>
```

My intentions are to load only the scss and js specific of each controller.

Comment: `%w( home.css, home.coffe )` returns `["home.css,", "home.coffe"]
` try `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css home.coffe )`, restart the server and check again

Comment: yupi! It works. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: adding it to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%w` creates an array of words using whitespace to separate each value

```
%w( home.css, home.coffe )
```

returns

```
["home.css,", "home.coffe"]
```

change code to

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css home.coffe )
```

Comment: Right on the corner. Thanks dude!